# PHP error closing a mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a very simple function:

```
function closeConn(){
    mysql_close($conn);
}
```

`$conn` is the connection variable - it connects ok but i get this error if i try and call it:

> Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Any **real** reason to close connection explicitly?

Comment: Any **real** reason not to use `mysqli`?

Comment: always been a bit hazy on when to close connection, so no, not a real reason :)

Comment: Any **real** reason to use `mysqli` if it is `PDO`?

Comment: why are people emphasising real :) but not any particular reason, is mysqli better?

Comment: @benhowdle89: yes, `PDO` is better (`mysqli` is better as well, but personally I prefer `PDO`). Just try it and see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is, `$conn` variable is empty.

Either pass it as an argument to your function:

```
function closeConn($conn){
    mysql_close($conn);
}

closeConn($conn);
```

or just don't use it at all and let PHP decide which connection to close (by default, tha last one that was opened)

```
function closeConn(){
    mysql_close();
}
```

or just don't close the connection at all. PHP does it for you anyway, when the script's execution ends.